# Compare and replace text if present in a .csv database

Tags: python

below I ask you this question:
This code:

```
from ogn.client import AprsClient
from ogn.parser import parse, ParseError


def inRange_square(s, minLat, maxLat, minLon, maxLon, minAlt, maxAlt):
    if s.get('longitude', 0) < minLon or s['longitude'] > maxLon or s['latitude'] < minLat or s['latitude']>maxLat or s['altitude']<minAlt or s['altitude']>maxAlt :

        return False

    return True


def processPlane(plane):
    if(inRange_square(plane, 46.1368, 46.1796, 8.8374, 8.9057, 210, 1000)):
    #if(inRange_square(plane, 46.127356, 46.441491, 9.276551, 8.460816, 210, 1000)):
        print("The plane is in range")
        print(plane.get**('name')**, plane.get('ground_speed'), plane.get('altitude'))
    #print('Received  {raw_message}'.format(**beacon))
    else:
        #print("The plane is not in range,")
        'odd'

def process_beacon(raw_message):
   try:
       beacon = parse(raw_message)
       #print('Received  {raw_message}'.format(**beacon))
       processPlane(beacon)
   except ParseError as e:
       #print('Error, {}'.format(e.message))
       print( raw_message )


client = AprsClient(aprs_user='N0CALL')
client.connect()

try:
    client.run(callback=process_beacon, autoreconnect=True)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\nStop ogn gateway')
    client.disconnect()
```

Shows an identifier (name) that corresponds to the Device Type in this database

```
#DEVICE_TYPE,DEVICE_ID,AIRCRAFT_MODEL,**REGISTRATION**,CN,TRACKED,IDENTIFIED
'F','000000','HPH 304CZ-17','OK-7777','KN','Y','Y'
'O','000001','Paraglider','','','Y','Y'
'F','000002','LS-6 18','OY-XRG','G2','Y','Y'
'F','00000D','Ka-8','D-1749','W5','Y','Y'
'O','000015','Paraglider','36445','','Y','Y'
'F','000038','SF-25','F-CKBC','','Y','Y'
'F','0000FD','Taurus','F-JRDN','DN','Y','Y'
'F','000114','','','','N','N'
'F','000146','Paraglider','antwilk','','Y','Y'
'F','000287','Paraglider','32712','','Y','Y'
'F','000296','Unknown','D-IEST','','Y','Y'
'F','000338','Unknown','','','Y','Y'
'F','000368','PIK-20 B','C-GORE','GP','Y','Y'
'F','000503','SZD-48-1 Jantar Std 2','SP-3152','DG','Y','Y'
'F','000597','LS-6','D-8997','IV','Y','Y'
'F','000617','ASW-20','OE-5292','A2','Y','Y'
'F','000634','Ultralight','D-MJPH','','Y','Y'
```

What I would like is for the program to replace the name identifier with the aeronautical abbreviation REGISTRATION in the database.

I searched the internet / Forum but I did not understand how to do it, in fact I could not find anything.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Which column corresponds to name identifier ?

Comment: Name identifier corresponds to DEVICE_ID  to replace with REGISTRATION

Comment: Please check if the table in this PDF can be used to enumarate your DEVICE_ID row. https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/List%20of%20EASA%20acronyms%20and%20abbreviations%20%2813022018%29%28v10%29.pdf

Comment: Probably, yes you could